# Selenium (C#) - How to get a string of the elements attributes

Tags: c#, html, selenium, attributes

Is there a way to get a string of all the attributes that are within a particular element?

For example, let's say my element is the following in the webpage:

```
<input id="SandBox1" checked="" class="float_right red white_stripes" value ="654288">
```

If it possible to get a string variable from this where it would have the attribute names and their values all in one string?

Comment: With your given example, what is your expected string?

Comment: The string that I was hoping to get was something like this:
id="SandBox1" checked="" class="float_right red white_stripes" value ="654288"

Comment: Using javascript executor with the following query: Element.outerHTML

Comment: What is your exact business case? Why are you looking for `id="SandBox1" checked="" class="float_right red white_stripes" value ="654288"` dropping the `<input>` tag?

Comment: @DebanjanB Well, the issue that I'm having is trying to find out if a particular attribute in the tag is present.  And based on if it is present, I would like to perform a certain action that would follow different logic then if it wasn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should do that for you.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var elem = driver.FindElement(By.Id("SandBox1"));

string attributes = (string)js.ExecuteScript("var re = /<[^ ]+([^>]+)/i; return re.exec(arguments[0].outerHtml)[1];", elem);
```

But it would in cases where attributes also have a `>` in the value

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for, but I ran it a couple of times and the string keeps coming up null.  I'll keep experimenting with it though and get back to you on this.

Comment: can you try replacing `outerHtml` with `outerHTML`?